# How to join two or more objects that are in an array? Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, join

I want to join two objects that are inside an array:

```
const test = [{name: ""}, {age: ""}, {nac: ""}];
```

I need it to look like this:

```
const test2 = [{name: "", age: "", nac: ""}];
```

I tried with: Object.assign () but I can't get it.

Any other ideas I can try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```js
const test = [{name: ""}, {age: ""}, {nac: ""}];
const test2 = [Object.assign({}, ...test)];
console.log(test2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array.prototype.reduce` function that will be useful when reducing an array to a single value. I have given example below

```
const test = [{name: ""}, {age: ""}, {nac: ""}];
const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => {
  for (var key in currentValue) {
    accumulator[key] = currentValue[key];
  }
  return accumulator;
};

var finalObj = test.reduce(reducer, {});
console.log(finalObj);
console.log([finalObj]);
```